# Increase Counter if Items Exist in a Table Using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops

I need to increase a counter if certain words exist in a table using jQuery. My counter only increases by 1 when I expect it should increase by 2.

HTML & jQuery below:

```js
var counter = 0;

$($(".ProductSKULabel:contains('LY-')").length || $(".ProductSKULabel:contains('LYE-')").length || $(".ProductSKULabel:contains('HSE-')").length || $(".ProductSKULabel:contains('HS-')").length).each(function() {
  counter++;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="w3_tblCartContents" class="CartTable" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" style="width:100%;border-collapse:collapse;">
  <tbody>
    <tr class=" CartHeader">
      <th></th>
      <th class="ProductSKUColumn" colspan="2">Product</th>
      <th>Qty</th>
      <th>Total</th>
    </tr>
    <tr class="AlternatingRowStyle">
      <td class="ProductSKUColumn" align="left" colspan="2"><a class="ItemNameLabel" href="/Product/Top-Loading-All-Purpose-Vinyl-Badge-Holders---3-x-4---Clip-Attachment---Clear-HSE-6-C-CLR-96101.htm?cartprodid=28011557">Top-Loading All-Purpose Vinyl Badge Holders - 3" x 4" - Clip Attachment - Clear</a><br>SKU:
        <a class="ProductSKULabel" href="/Product/Top-Loading-All-Purpose-Vinyl-Badge-Holders---3-x-4---Clip-Attachment---Clear-HSE-6-C-CLR-96101.htm?cartprodid=28011557">HSE-6-C-CLR</a></td>
      <td class="currency"><span class="ItemExtendedPriceLabel">37.00</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="RowStyle" onmouseover="document.getElementById('w3_SurveyContainer28011561').style.display = '';" onmouseout="document.getElementById('w3_SurveyContainer28011561').style.display = 'none';">
      <td class="ProductSKUColumn" align="left" colspan="2"><a class="ItemNameLabel" href="/Product/38-Adjustable-Polyester-Lanyard-with-Bulldog-Clip-LY-13-R-CC-38580.htm?cartprodid=28011561">Adjustable Polyester Lanyard with Bulldog Clip</a><br>SKU: <a class="ProductSKULabel" href="/Product/38-Adjustable-Polyester-Lanyard-with-Bulldog-Clip-LY-13-R-CC-38580.htm?cartprodid=28011561">LY-13-R-CC</a></td>
      <td
        class="currency"><span class="ItemExtendedPriceLabel">179.00</span></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: What console errors are you getting in developer tools?

Comment: I'm not getting any errors...  my loop is stopping after it finds one instance. I expect my counter to be at 2 based on the example I gave but it only shows 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure about that approach you are using, so I'll present an alternative:

[.filter()](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) + [.text()](http://api.jquery.com/text/) + [.match()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_match.asp)

HIH

```js
var counter = $(".ProductSKULabel").filter(function(){
  return $(this).text().match(/(HSE-)|(LY-)|(HS-)|(LY-)/)!==null;
}).length;

console.log(counter);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="w3_tblCartContents" class="CartTable" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" style="width:100%;border-collapse:collapse;">
  <tbody>
    <tr class=" CartHeader">
      <th></th>
      <th class="ProductSKUColumn" colspan="2">Product</th>
      <th>Qty</th>
      <th>Total</th>
    </tr>
    <tr class="AlternatingRowStyle">
      <td class="ProductSKUColumn" align="left" colspan="2"><a class="ItemNameLabel" href="/Product/Top-Loading-All-Purpose-Vinyl-Badge-Holders---3-x-4---Clip-Attachment---Clear-HSE-6-C-CLR-96101.htm?cartprodid=28011557">Top-Loading All-Purpose Vinyl Badge Holders - 3" x 4" - Clip Attachment - Clear</a><br>SKU:
        <a class="ProductSKULabel" href="/Product/Top-Loading-All-Purpose-Vinyl-Badge-Holders---3-x-4---Clip-Attachment---Clear-HSE-6-C-CLR-96101.htm?cartprodid=28011557">HSE-6-C-CLR</a></td>
      <td class="currency"><span class="ItemExtendedPriceLabel">37.00</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="RowStyle" onmouseover="document.getElementById('w3_SurveyContainer28011561').style.display = '';" onmouseout="document.getElementById('w3_SurveyContainer28011561').style.display = 'none';">
      <td class="ProductSKUColumn" align="left" colspan="2"><a class="ItemNameLabel" href="/Product/38-Adjustable-Polyester-Lanyard-with-Bulldog-Clip-LY-13-R-CC-38580.htm?cartprodid=28011561">Adjustable Polyester Lanyard with Bulldog Clip</a><br>SKU: <a class="ProductSKULabel" href="/Product/38-Adjustable-Polyester-Lanyard-with-Bulldog-Clip-LY-13-R-CC-38580.htm?cartprodid=28011561">LY-13-R-CC</a></td>
      <td
        class="currency"><span class="ItemExtendedPriceLabel">179.00</span></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Works perfectly and is a lot less code that I came up with since posting this question!

Answer (score 0):

Try to use Regular Expression [How to use](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_regexp.asp)

```js
var regex = /^vexillology$/i;

function getValue()  {
    return document.getElementById("myinput").value;
}

function test() {
    alert(regex.test(getValue()));
}

function match() {
    alert(getValue().match(regex));    
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="myinput" value="vexillology"/>
<button id="testBtn" onclick=test()>test</button>
<button id="matchBtn" onclick=match()>match</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your each statement is not iterating over a selector. I modified it so the evaluation is performed inside of the each.

```
var counter = 0;

$(".ProductSKULabel").each(function() {
    if($(this).text().indexOf("LY-") >=0 || $(this).text().indexOf("LYE-") || $(this).text().indexOf("HSE-") ) {
        counter++;
    }
});
```